# Finding Correct exception to catch

Tags: java, string, exception, try-catch, throw

Which exception can i use to check if the input has the right number of "/"
The input should be like DD/MM/YYYY

```
try{
                String str = text.getText();
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str);
                String DD = st.nextToken("/");
                String MM = st.nextToken("/");
                String YYYY = st.nextToken();
}
catch( ???){

}
```

Comment: Why not try it and see?

Comment: do you really need exception to check it?

Comment: In C#, you could catch the base class `Exception` and see, using a breakpoint, what type it actually is. I assume the same can be done using Java

Comment: That Exception is  `StringDoesNotContainRightNumberOfSlashException`

Comment: From the [JavaDoc for `StringTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) _StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code._ So the answer is don't catch any exception, rewrite your code. In this case you seem to be parsing a date so why not use the [correct approach](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find it in the javadoc of nextToken.
It says it will throw a NoSuchElementException when  there is no more token.

That said you should better not use the try/catch but test it using the hasMoreTokens method.

Comment: As Boris the Spider pointed out, it is even better to use the DateFormat approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Custom Exception** for this but for that you need to declare **method** which validate your date (No of slashes).

Try Like this

```
   public class Demo
      {


  public static void main (String[] args) {

      try {
        new MyClass().metToValidate("01/12/2014");
          } catch (A e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
          }

      }

}
class A extends Exception{}


class MyClass{
      public void metToValidate(String dateText) throws A{


                if( dateText.charAt(2) == '/'&& dateText.charAt(5) == '/' )
                    System.out.println("DATE IS OK"); 

                else
                    throw new A();
      }
    }
```

Comment: +1, but you can provide executable example...that would be better answer.

Comment: Edit is always there :) and OP is waiting, not me ;)

Comment: `^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])` this RegEx will do the job. this accepts dd/MM/yyyy with leap years, Valid years : from 1600 to 9999

Answer (score 0):

The exception throws by nextToken is NoSuchElementException.

Answer (score 0):

```
            String str = "12/21223";
            int counter = 0;
            for( int i=0; i<str.length(); i++ ) {
                if( str.charAt(i) == '/' ) {
                    counter++;
                } 
            }
            if(counter == 3){
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str);
                String DD = st.nextToken("/");
                String MM = st.nextToken("/");
                String YYYY = st.nextToken();
                System.out.println(str);
            }else{
                System.out.println("Exception");
            }
```